# Base Class type for ILogger<T> using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a base class that does some work, including logging. I have an ILogger dependency injected into the constructor

```
public abstract class BaseClassExample
{
    protected readonly ILogger<BaseClassExample> logger;

    public BaseClassExample(ILogger<BaseClassExample> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
}
```

And I want to have classes implement BaseClassExample, and do their own work too, also including logging.

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClassExample
{
    protected readonly ILogger<DerivedClass> logger;

    public DerivedClass(ILogger<DerivedClass> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Is this the right way of doing things? Am I supposed to get the implementing class's type for logging for the base class? Should I have a separate instance of a logger (with the DerivedClass's type) or try and use the same one as the base class?

Comment: I think you could just take `ILogger` in the base and your derived would pass down a `Logger<Derived>`

Answer (score 40):

use a none generic ILogger in your base class, but `ILogger<DerivedClass>` in your derived class. This way you can simply pass the ILogger to your base class if needed:

```
public abstract class BaseClassExample
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public class BaseClassExample(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClassExample
{
    private readonly ILogger<DerivedClass> logger;

    public class BaseClassExample(ILogger<DerivedClass> logger)
                  :base(logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
}
```

this way not only you can use it easier if you somehow end up with two derived class you can use ILogger in both of them.

Comment: I do this, and I get a warning that logger in the DerivedClass hides logger in the BaseClassExample. Is this expected or bad?

Comment: It is probably because of access modifiers. make ILogger private in both the derived and the base class. this way they don't clash with each other. and the warning should go away. Nonetheless, you can ignore that warning

Comment: @F_IVI_L, why not `ILogger<DerivedClass>`? I cannot seem to find documentation about this.

Comment: @ChadK make `logger` `protected` in the base class and remove the `logger` field from the derrived class.

Answer (score 5):

Fixing @F_IVI_L's answer.

To inject a logger to a base class while still allowing the child class to use (inherit) it, do this:

```cs
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected readonly ILogger<BaseClass> logger;

    protected BaseClass(ILogger<BaseClass> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(ILogger<DerivedClass> logger) :
        base(logger)
    { }
}
```

Even though Intellisense will show you that `this.logger` is of type `ILogger<BaseClass>`, it will actually be of type `ILogger<DerivedClass>` when used in `DerivedClass` (because of `ILogger<out T>` being covariant as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#type-parameters) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)).

Comment: As @Wouter points out in his answer, `ILogger<T>` is covariant meaning that you can just use `ILogger<BaseClass>` in `BaseClass` and not worry that it will actually be an object of `ILogger<DerivedClass>`. No need to use the non-generic `ILogger`

Comment: Indeed, @Mog0, thanks. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

Use `HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger>` if you are using ASP.NET Core like bellow:

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> : Controller
{
    private ILogger<T> _loggerInstance;
        protected ILogger<T> _logger => _loggerInstance ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger<T>>();
}
```

and if you are using Razor pages:

```
class BasePageModel<T> : PageModel where T : class
{
    private ILogger<T> _loggerInstance;
        protected ILogger<T> _logger => _loggerInstance ??= HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger<T>>();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `ILogger<T>` is covariant you can use `ILogger<BaseClass>` in the constructor of the baseclass and call it with an `ILogger<DerviedClass>`.

In either approach using `ILogger` or `ILogger<T>` the injected logger starts to write to a different category than the intended one. Meaning your base class will log in the derived logger category.

Comment: This should be the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the declaration:

```
public interface ILogger<out TCategoryName> : ILogger
```

it gives you two options:

1. use `Ilogger` because `ILogger<T>` is an `ILogger`,
2. use `ILogger<BaseClass>` because `ILogger<DerivedClass>` is also an `ILogger<BaseClass>`.

Comment: I do not understand why that was considered a bad answer while having extra member that is not used is considered a good one. I am voting up on this one and I consider defining an unused member is as bad as unused variables in your code. This approach shown here is right and it works.