# The correct way to DI ILogger<Class> in the derived classes

Tags: logging, serilog, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm using `Serilog.AspNetCore` with ASP.NET Core 5.0. What is the correct way to DI `ILogger<Class>`?

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSerilog((context, _, configuration) => configuration.ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration))
        .ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostingContext, services) =>
        {
            ...

            var strategyTypes = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(StrategyBase))?.GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(StrategyBase)));

            if (strategyTypes != null)
            {
                foreach (var type in strategyTypes)
                {
                    services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(StrategyBase), type, ServiceLifetime.Singleton));
                }
            }

            services.AddSingleton<IStrategyFactory, StrategyFactory>();
        });

public interface IStrategy
{
}

public abstract class StrategyBase : IStrategy
{
    private readonly ILogger<StrategyBase> _logger;

    protected StrategyBase(ILogger<StrategyBase> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}

public class TestStrategy : StrategyBase
{
    public TestStrategy(ILogger<TestStrategy> logger) : base(logger)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at, it seems the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60344757/base-class-type-for-iloggert-using-dependency-injection/60344886#60344886

Comment: @F_IVI_L, I did before I made the question. I'm getting `Parameter can be of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger'`. Screenshot in addition: https://i.imgur.com/klNXNnp.png